# Include a Region in Page Template is not working in DXA 1.5 Java

Tags: 2013-sp1, web8, dxa, dxa-java, dxa-1.5

We are trying to add a Region for our *Global alerts site wide* in Page Template.

Detailed implementation steps:

CT:
[image: Component template]

Include PT:
[image: Include PT]

PT:
[image: Page template]

Page:
[image: Page]

Initialize:

```
@RegisteredViewModel(viewName = "NWAlert", modelClass = RegionModelImpl.class),
@RegisteredViewModel(viewName = "AlertMessage", modelClass = AlertModel.class)
```

`AlertRegion`:

```
<jsp:useBean id="region" type="com.sdl.webapp.common.api.model.RegionModel" scope="request"/>
<jsp:useBean id="markup" type="com.sdl.webapp.common.markup.Markup" scope="request"/>
<div ${markup.region(region)}>
    <dxa:entities/>
</div>
```

`Page.jsp`:

```
<dxa:region name="NWAlert" />
```

Workaround:

I can see the `Alert` related data in Page Model data JSON response. Looks the content pre-rendered is happening properly.

When I do debug, I can see the Region of `NWAlert` was properly initializing and it’s not throwing any error but still the Region part is not displaying in the Page.

> [/WEB-INF/Views/xxx/Region/NWAlert.jsp]: Initialization successful

Also, I noticed when I do view source of my Page the Region tag is appending without data.

```
<div typeof="Region" resource="NWAlert">
<!--  Start Region: {title: "NWAlert", allowedComponentTypes: [{schema: "tcm:xx-xx-x", template: "tcm:xx-xx-xx"}], minOccurs: 0}  --> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Following the example of a available Include Page in DXA 1.5, lets take the **Content Tools** for example (https://github.com/sdl/dxa-modules/blob/release/1.5/webapp-java/dxa-module-core/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/WEB-INF/Views/Core/Region/Content-Tools.jsp). You should have a Region View for the Include Page. That should be a copy of https://github.com/sdl/dxa-modules/blob/release/1.5/webapp-java/dxa-module-core/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/WEB-INF/Views/Core/Page/IncludePage.jsp basically (looks like your `Page.jsp` is an extract of that).

Then for the Region that will be rendered as part of the Include Page, you will need the following Region View markup:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="dxa" uri="http://www.sdl.com/tridion-dxa" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="xpm" uri="http://www.sdl.com/tridion-xpm" %>

<jsp:useBean id="region" type="com.sdl.webapp.common.api.model.RegionModel" scope="request"/>
<jsp:useBean id="markup" type="com.sdl.webapp.common.markup.Markup" scope="request"/>
<xpm:button region="${region}"/>

<div ${markup.region(region)}>
    <dxa:regions/>
</div>
```

(similar to https://github.com/sdl/dxa-modules/blob/release/1.5/webapp-java/dxa-module-core/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/WEB-INF/Views/Core/Region/Content-Tools.jsp)

Then in that Include Page, you will add Content, which will again be in a Region, and that Region needs the following Region View markup:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="dxa" uri="http://www.sdl.com/tridion-dxa" %>
<jsp:useBean id="region" type="com.sdl.webapp.common.api.model.RegionModel" scope="request"/>
<jsp:useBean id="markup" type="com.sdl.webapp.common.markup.Markup" scope="request"/>

<div ${markup.region(region)}>
    <dxa:entities/>
</div>
```

(similar to https://github.com/sdl/dxa-modules/blob/release/1.5/webapp-java/dxa-module-core/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/WEB-INF/Views/Core/Region/Tools.jsp as defined by the CT **Social Sharing [Tools]** for example)

So my example defines the following views:

- IncludePage [Page View]
- SocialSharing [Entity View]
- Tools [Region View]
- Content-Tools [Region View]

But from your description I make up the following:

- IncludePage [Page View]
- AlertMessage [Entity View]
- NWAlert [Region View]
- nwalert [Region View]

And the last one has a naming conflict, since both the Include Region and its Entity Region have the same name. If you follow the example of the **Content Tools** Include Page, you should name the Include Page different than the Region, so you can register both of those Regions and add the missing Region View (jsp).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for you suggestion @Tory and Bart Koopman

I have implemented as below. Its working now.

1. HomePage [Page View]
2. IncludePage [Page View]
3. AlertMessage [EntityView]
4. NWAlert [Region View]
5. GlobalAlert [Region View]

CT:
[image: CT]

`IncludePage` PT:
[image: IncludePage PT]

`HomePage` PT:
[image: HomePage PT]

Page:
[image: Page]

`AlertMessage` Model and `AlertMessage` View :

Initialize:

```
@RegisteredViewModel(viewName = "HomePage", modelClass = PageModelImpl.class),
@RegisteredViewModel(viewName = "IncludePage", modelClass = PageModelImpl.class),
@RegisteredViewModel(viewName = "GlobalAlert", modelClass = RegionModelImpl.class),
@RegisteredViewModel(viewName = "NWAlert", modelClass = RegionModelImpl.class),
@RegisteredViewModel(viewName = "AlertMessage", modelClass = AlertModel.class),
```

`GlobalAlert.jsp`:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="dxa" uri="http://www.sdl.com/tridion-dxa"%>

<jsp:useBean id="region" type="com.sdl.webapp.common.api.model.RegionModel" scope="request"/>
<jsp:useBean id="markup" type="com.sdl.webapp.common.markup.Markup" scope="request"/>

<div ${markup.region(region)}>
    <dxa:entities/>
</div>
```

`NWAlert.jsp`:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="dxa" uri="http://www.sdl.com/tridion-dxa"%>

<jsp:useBean id="region" type="com.sdl.webapp.common.api.model.RegionModel" scope="request"/>
<jsp:useBean id="markup" type="com.sdl.webapp.common.markup.Markup" scope="request"/>

<div ${markup.region(region)}>
    <dxa:region name="GlobalAlert" />
</div>
```

`IncludePage.jsp`:

```
<dxa:region name="GlobalAlert" />
```

`HomePage.jsp`:

```
<dxa:region name="NWAlert" />
```